# Discrepancy between stringr and base R regular expressions

Tags: r, regex

I have this rather annoying to read regular expression.

```
pattern = "(?<=(?<=[0-9])[dD](?=[0-9]))[0-9]+"
```

It was generated automatically so human readability or efficiency is less of an issue than validity. It was meant to parse RPG dice type syntax, such as `10d20`. Specifically it is supposed to match the `20`.

If I use the old method of string matching in R

```
text = '10d20'
regmatches(text,regexpr(pattern,text,perl = TRUE))
```

I get what I want, which is 20, however using the more modern method of string matching

```
stringr::str_match(text,  pattern)
```

I get nothing. I was wondering what causes this difference between the two methods and how can I avoid issues like this in the future.

Comment: PCRE and ICU regex libraries differ in many ways. It appears ICU (`str_match`) does not like nested lookbehinds checking for a pattern at the same location. You just need to use a normal regex for that, `(?<=[0-9][dD])[0-9]+`. The `(?=[0-9])` is totally redundant as you are consuming digits after the lookbehind. There is no need of another lookbehind inside the outer one since the digit you want to require is before `d`, and it can be checked with `[0-9]` itself inside the same single lookbehind.

Comment: I see. That is a shame. The regex is created using smaller building blocks that include lookbehinds themselves so it is problematic for this use case that one cannot naively merge things together and use stringr. Another curiosity here is what does ICU thinks its doing when there are nested lookbehinds. Because it doesn't throw an error here so it must be trying to do something

Comment: It seems that ICU does not support nested lookbehinds in general, no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you *need* the extras that come with ICU (via `stringi` which `stringr` is merely a crutch helper wrapper for) there's no need for woe.

In fact, there's a pkg with less marketing power than `tidyverse`-based pkgs called `stringb` which puts "data first" (like `string[ir]`) and relieves you from base regexp inanity. Vis-a-vis:

```
library(stringb)

pattern <- "(?<=(?<=[0-9])[dD](?=[0-9]))[0-9]+"

text <- '10d20'

text_extract(text, pattern, perl = TRUE)
## [1] "20"
```

You get saner syntax without relying on a massive compiled code dependencies and 1-away<sup>*</sup> `stringr` abstraction. Bellisimo!

---

<sup>* TBFair: the `stringb` package also has 1-away abstraction from base R functions but the saner syntax makes up for it IMO (unlike `stringr`).</sup>

Comment: I guess the technical correct answer would be all that stuff about nested negative lookbehinds not being supported but stringb looks nice and I'll probably end up using that in my workaround so I might as well accept this.

Comment: @OganM You then probably need to change the title to some "What other 'modern' functions can handle a PCRE regex". This answer is just the same what you are using, a PCRE engine.

Comment: Hmm that also makes the text of the question completely out of context though. If you wrote yours down, I could switch the accepted answer and keep this one as a useful note? As a side note, I can see why stringb isn't that popular. It seems frozen and I immediately found issues with how it treats arguments that were meant to be passed on to base R functions (there are at least 2 cases of them going nowhere). A few pull requests can fix that but will have to see if I have the time.